# Crawler not correctly sorting data when a column only occurs in some of the CSVs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm attempting to set up a data lake. We've dumped a bunch of CSVs into S3 under the format (oversimplified for question asking):

```
bucket
|-- report_type1
    |-- file1.csv
    |-- file2.csv
|-- report_type2
    |-- file3.csv
    |-- file4.csv
    |-- file5.csv
|-- report_type3
 etc . . .
```

I want to grab from this lake and push parts of the data into redshift, as well as making the lake athena queryable. To do that, I'm kicking off a crawler via Glue. The crawler runs, created a bunch of tables (report_type1, report_type2, report_type3, ...) and completes.

However, when I query with Athena to check if it worked, I'm seeing that some columns aren't being appropriately assigned in Athena. For example, file1.csv looks like this:

```
col0, col1, col2
0, 1, 3
2, 4, 9
2, 1, 7
```

but file2.csv looks like this:

```
col0, new_col, col1, col2
1, 3, 12, 8
3,  , 10, 2
7,  , 0,
```

So when processing the second dataset, we found an extra column. It's a legitimate columns that's supposed to be recorded... but since it wasn't in the first file's data, it wasn't added there.

What I end up seeing is, I'll query like:

`SELECT col1 FROM report_type1`

in athena and I'll see that col2 has been shifted around and now I'm seeing values for col2 under the name of col1. My assumption is that it's something to do with the extra columns coming in. I've tried running the crawler with all the different "what to do when you find a new column"

```
* Update the table definition in the data catalog.
* Add new columns only.
* Ignore the change and don't update the table in the data catalog
```

None has worked to solve this problem. Is there a setting I can use that will not break in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The structure of the Files are immutable. Athena is just a query service on S3 files. The "Add new columns only" work when the columns are appended at the end and not anywhere.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select checkbox

> Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table.

in crawler